# Error tree.actions.filter(...).map(...).at is not a function while generating component using angular CLI 14

Tags: angular-cli, angular-components, angular14

When I try to generate component using angular CLI
ng generate component test --skip-import
or
ng generate component test -m app.module.ts
I have an error
tree.actions.filter(...).map(...).at is not a function

Does anyone know how to fix it?

[ng version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NQW4.png)

I tried to update the Angular CLI to the latest version globally and in the project.
I tried to remove and reinstall the @angular/cli package globally and in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I have my own case when the issue manifested itself. I tracked it down till the commit were Cypress was installed, which modified (among others) following lines in the `angular.json` - part of the git diff on that commit:

```
"cli": {
-    "analytics": false
+    "analytics": false,
+    "schematicCollections": [
+      "@cypress/schematic",
+      "@schematics/angular"
+    ]
}
```

After I removed `schematicCollections` field, Cypress seems not to be affected, but `ng g c <component-name>` does the job again.

This does not look like a good solution, and maybe it happens altogether just because I use kinda obsolete `node@14` `@angular/cli@14` and the latest `cypress@17` in this particular project.